# Simple java SOAP webservice - consistent poor performance

Tags: java, performance, soap

I have a very simple webservice that is essetially an interface between a database and external callers.

When calling the service methods directly during unit testing the results are processed instantly. Strangly when running a stub ws on my local machine the results will always take almost exactly 5 minutes, no matter what query I am executing. The result time is too consistent to be anything other than a problem.

The ws is built using the built in Java 6 JAX-ws libraries inc. using the Java 6 HttpServer and Xalan as the xslt processor.

Has anyone come across a smilar issue ?

Regards,
Andy

Turns out that this was the same issue as decribed in the first comment link below. Thank you. By default the version of Axis used to generate the client was generating with http 1.0 instead of the expected 1.1.

Comment: Might this be referring to a similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985963/eclipse-generated-web-service-client-extremely-slow

Answer (score 0):

Ha, i've never seen a simple java SOAP webservice =)

That said, the fact that the results "take almost exactly 5 minutes, no matter what..." sounds suspiciously like coding error.  Is something supposed to be sleeping for 300 ms but is actually blocking for 300 seconds?

Comment: Yeah checked all of that. Has to be an infrastructure problem that will be hard to decipher.  I can run the service and execute all methods fine, just not when I do it via a stub ws client. Baffling.