# "delay" in delivering WebService reply when using sun HttpServer

Tags: java, web-services, tcp, delay, com.sun.net.httpserver

I'm writing a standalone application that implements a Web Service, for which the Endpoint is published using the embedded Sun HttpServer. I have an odd issue with this, where in a specific deployment situation, there is an apparent delay between the **server** processing /sending the reply and the **client** receiving the reply.

Let me give a few scenarios:

Case 1) Working: server is running inside Eclipse, which uses OpenJDK 1.6.0_23 as runtime. Client is implemented with axis (not axis2!) and is running on Solaris x86 inside JBoss (must admit I don't know the exact Java version used, but I suspect a Java 5 version).

Case 2) Working: server is running on Solaris x86 with java 1.6.0_26, client is running inside Eclipse with OpenJDK 1.6.0_23.

Case 3) Not working: server is running on Solaris x86 with java 1.6.0_26, client is on Solaris x86 with axis on Solaris x86 (again, suspect it's Java 5, not 6).

I'm wondering if I could be suffering from the following Java bug, which is fixed in 1.6.0_30 (assuming that OpenJDK 1.6.0_xx does not suffer the same bug)?

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7068416

But if that's the case, then why would case 2 work? Can the **client** somehow control the TCP_NODELAY on the **server** side?

On the exact delays that i have observed: I have 2 web services, published on different contexts. Eg 2 different WSDLs. The client has (obviously) separate (axis 1) bindings for each service. For one service, I see a consistent delay of exactly 150 seconds, for the other service the delay is consistently 300 seconds. Do these values ring a bell to anybody?

Maarten

**Edit**
I am now leaning towards the cause and solution in [Eclipse Generated Web Service Client Extremely Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985963/eclipse-generated-web-service-client-extremely-slow). Can't test at the moment as I'm sitting in a hotel room without access to the system.

Comment: Let me add the following: when I say "the server processing/sending the reply", I am talking about returning from the method implementing the @WebMethod. I've inserted a SOAPHandler into my code that prints out the outgoing SOAP reply, and that's how I am measuring the time between my server application "sending" the response, and the client "receiving" the response.

Answer (score 0):

OK, managed to solve this, by telling Axis to use the CommonsHttpSender instead of the default HttpSender. Since the relevant application already had the prerequisite jars for that inside its WEB-INF/lib directory, that wasn't such a big deal.

To make Axis (1.4) use the CommonsHttpSender, create a "client-config.wsdd" file in the following location (note: this was the non-obvious part that caused me quite a few headaches):

```
MY.ear/MY.war/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/axis/client/client-config.wsdd
```

with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<deployment 
    name="commonsHTTPConfig" 
    xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" 
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

   <!-- use CommonsHTTPSender instead of the default HTTPSender -->
  <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender" />  

  <transport name="local" pivot = "java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalSender" /> 
  <transport name="java" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.java.JavaSender" /> 
</deployment>
```

Restart your application. After this change, Axis will use HTTP/1.1 to make web service calls, which seems to be all that was needed to correct this annoying delay. Seems that there is *something* in the HTTP protocol specs (or perhaps Axis' implementation) that doesn't like a HTTP/1.1 response to a HTTP/1.0 request.

Maarten